# flex timer - appear disappare

Tags: apache-flex, timer

I have an object in flex - which i want to appear upon a button clicked, disappear after 10 seconds or if the object is closed, and reappear if that same button pressed.

i've tried something like this:

```
public class my_obj
{
  private var _myTimer: Timer;

     public function my_obj()
     {
           _myTimer = new Timer(10000);

     }
     private function init(): void
     {
           _myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimeout);
            _myTimer.start();
     }

     private function onTimerTimeOut(event: TimerEvent): void
     {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(CLOSE_EVENT));
     }
}
```

what am i missing?
Thanks!

Comment: What's your problem? Why "onTimeout" and "onTimerTimeOut"? Did you try to debug? Give us more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fine. Here's the working code sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Panel width="100%" height="400" creationComplete="my_obj()">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                private var _myTimer: Timer;

                public function my_obj():void
                {
                    _myTimer = new Timer(10000);

                }
                private function init(): void
                {
                    toggleBtn.visible = true;

                    _myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimeout);
                    _myTimer.start();
                }

                private function onTimeout(event: TimerEvent): void
                {
                    toggleBtn.visible = false;
                    //dispatchEvent(new Event(CLOSE_EVENT));
                }

                private function hideIt(): void
                {
                    toggleBtn.visible = false;

                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <s:Button label="Some Button" click="init()"/>
        <s:Button id="toggleBtn" label="Appeared on 'Some Button' click. Click to close it." click="hideIt()" visible="false"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: thanks @M.D. - the only problem is that i call this object from another object (it always exists - only appears and disappears) how can i reset the time every time i go "visible=true"?

Comment: @qqqqq Just add _myTimer.reset(); after you call visible = true. That will reset the timer back to Zero. Make sure you call _myTimer.start() to start it again. Reset won't start it by itself.

Comment: @qqqqq, It should be mentioned that this is a fairly horrible way to do a 'timeout'.  Why not just use a show effect and then a hide effect with a delay of 10 seconds?  It's simpler and a lot less code.  Furthermore, the timer never resets or stops and keeps calling the timeout function.